# binary file from global attribute cdf

Tags: python, attributes, global-variables, binaryfiles

I am not a python expert but I am using it.

What I have is a list of CDF files from which I want to extract a global attribute (which is of type CDF_DOUBLE) and write this variable into a single binary file. I am using *pycdf* for it.

I am able to extract the global attribute, but I am not able to write it into the binary file.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import zipfile
from spacepy import pycdf
input_path = '/home/mypath'
filelist = os.listdir(input_path)

for filename in filelist:
    fullfilename = input_path + '/' + filename
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(fullfilename, 'r')
    cdffile_zip = zfile.extract(zfile.namelist()[0], '/home/scratch/')

    cdffile = pycdf.CDF(cdffile_zip)
    zfile.close()
    glob_attr = cdffile.attrs['MY_GLOBAL_ATTR']

    with open('somefile.bin', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(glob_attr) <-- ***PROBLEM HERE***
        f.close()

    command = 'rm -f {}'.format(cdffile_zip)
    os.system(command)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your current code will overwrite the 'somefile.bin' for every filename in the filelist as it does not append and is closed for every file. so only the last entry is seen.

Comment: Hi Ivonet, thanks for your answer. Yes, I am aware of this, I just created a 'single' iteration loop. However, that was not the point of my question. I am not able to create the binary file with the global attribute even for just a single file. 
In my specific case I have a list of (zipped) cdf files.

Comment: Have you tried using [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#bytearray)?

Comment: Yes, I did try but for [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#bytearray) you need an integer as input, in my case the global attribute is of type double (CDF_DOUBLE, as I specified in the question). 
In fact if I use it I get this error:
 `TypeError: an integer is required`